# Messages between Master to Worker are not passed fully when using "Cluster Mode"

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, body-parser, data-uri

I am getting a VERY weird issue when working with cluster mode.

Running Express as my framework

Somehow while using express body parser during that time, the expected size > the received size inside the worker (which fails the API as a result).
The expected size of the body is correct (compared to the output from client) while the received size (after chunks aggregation) is smaller. This size inequality happens only if I pass in the body base64 url image (if I am replacing the base64 url with empty string) it works. I have added debug on the parser, and the diff is around 30KB +-(65933 vs 98143).

Happens only when using cluster mode (turn to false = works)

Seems like it is related to the size of the message, and not the type of encoding. Tried the same on a much smaller dataUrl string, and it worked. So it seems like a bug in clusterMode or some kind of size limitation in the inside mechanism.

We do see that in "body-parser" internals, we are not getting the full data

Update - tried with just 100kb body - still fails, so it is probably related to nodejs cluster mode and not to any kind of encodings.

Update #2 - works with 50KB fails in 80KB so the limit is somewhere in between

Found this: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-sticky/issues/6

Will work on a fix and update here

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - it is within the socket-io sticky connection that was used to setup the primary and workers.

We have published a possible fix here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-sticky/pull/9